# How to set channel map/layout in ALSA

Tags: linux, audio, alsa, pcm

I am struggling to set the channel map(a.k.a. channel layout) on my ALSA-backend computer.

The default output device is **"default."** I can't set the customized channel map for it. I also tried **"surround51"**, but it can't work neither.

Does anyone know how to set a channel map to ALSA?

Code: [gist link](https://gist.github.com/ChunMinChang/03741999c8f5e27dd655368b999870c0/73ffcc0e05a0c2163887b2e2eda98f7bd45394a8)

Comment: Does your hardware (which you have kept secret) actually support changing the channel map?

Comment: I use [Xonar DGX PCI-E](https://www.asus.com/Sound-Cards/Xonar_DGX/). How can I know whether it's available to change the channel map?

Comment: Search the output of "amixer contents" for controls with "chmap", and look whether those controls are writable. But the Xonar driver does not yet support this.